# assigning name to tree node using classes in Python

Tags: python, oop, binary-tree

how do I assign a name to the left child of the left child of the root? I am new with classes. the last two lines are where I try to make the assignment. Help is appreciated!

```
class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self,rootName):
        self.root = rootName
        self.leftChild = None
        self.rightChild = None

    def insertLeft(self,newNode):
        if self.leftChild == None:
            self.leftChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.leftChild = self.leftChild
            self.leftChild = t

    def insertRight(self,newNode):
        if self.rightChild == None:
            self.rightChild = BinaryTree(newNode)
        else:
            t = BinaryTree(newNode)
            t.rightChild = self.rightChild
            self.rightChild = t


    def getRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def getLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def setRootVal(self,obj):
        self.root = obj

    def getRootVal(self):
        return self.root


r = BinaryTree('a')
r.leftChild = 'b'
r.rightChild = 'c'

r.insertLeft = BinaryTree('b')
r.insertRight = BinaryTree('c')


r.getLeftChild().leftChild = 'd' 
r.leftChild.leftChild = 'd'
```

both of the last two statements give me this error: 'str' object has no attribute 'getRootVal'
I am trying to create a tree that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: You don't seem to understand how to use the `BinaryTree` class. What does the homework require you to do?

Comment: hi, trying to create a tree that looks like this above

Comment: `insertLeft` and `insertRight` are functions, not attributes. As such you should be doing `r.insertLeft('b')` and `r.insertRight('c')`. The code runs after this modification, although I agree with @Sweeper and you could implement this better.

Comment: thank you! first time doing OOP. What would be the better implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the interface of `BinaryTree`, you are supposed to call `insertLeft` and `insertRight` to add children to the tree, instead of:

```
r.leftChild = 'b'
r.rightChild = 'c'
```

`leftChild` and `rightChild` are supposed to be `BinaryTree` objects, not strings. Although you could write:

```
r.leftChild = BinaryTree('b')
r.rightChild = BinaryTree('c')
```

It doesn't handle the case when `leftChild` and `rightChild` are not `None`. This is why you should use `insertLeft` and `insertRight`, which does handle these cases for you:

```
r.insertLeft('b')
r.insertRight('c')
```

To insert `d`, `e` and `f`, we do it the same way using `insertLeft` and `insertRight`:

```
r.getLeftChild().insertRight('d')
r.getRightChild().insertLeft('e')
r.getRightChild().insertRight('f')
```